# getting other people's authorized facebook feeds programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

i am building an app where i can get chosen users feeds programmatically, i have tried looking through the facebook APIs and tried this:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                      parameters:@{ @"message": string,}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

but of course those are my feeds, 
all i need to do is get the authorized feeds (the ones u see in the browser) but filtered by user, is that doable?
if yes, can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks!

Comment: No, that is not doable. Endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/home has been removed a while ago, and there is no replacement.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but what about /user-id/feed ?

Comment: What about it? It only gets you the posts _“published by this person, or by others on this person's profile”_ ... and that does not seem to be what you want.